# How to create multi layer network with two inputs(x1, x2) in Python

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

I need to create mlp function. I have picture. This function have to work as show image. I don't understand how coding relation between weights and neurons. This random weights is correct? I have not much code

[image]

```py
import numpy as np


def ui_sigmoid(x, beta):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-beta*x))


def bi_sigmoid(x, beta):
    return np.tanh(beta*x)


def func(inputs):
    w1 = np.random.random((2, 3))
    w2 = np.random.random((1, 3))
```